scroll to element in vue3 composition API
I need to scroll to a v-if div after clicking a button and this is not working. Im trying the ref approach as follows:
import { onMounted } from 'vue';
export default {
  setup(context) {
    const confirmed = ref(false);
    const feedback = ref(null);

    function confirmSelection() {
      confirmed.value = true;
      
      this.$nextTick(() => {
        feedback.value.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth", block: "center" });
      });      
    }

    onMounted( () => {
        feedback.value = document.getElementById("feedback");
    })

    return {
      confirmed,
      confirmSelection,
    }
  },
}

So I have a div#feedback conditioned by v-if="confirmed" and I would like to scroll to it as soon as confirmed becomes true, on console I'm getting "this.$nextTick is not a funcion" as error.
Any ideas?

Can you add code for your template?

you need to import nextTick function first
import { onMounted, nextTick } from 'vue';

then use it
nextTick(() => {
   feedback.value.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth", block: "center" });
})

or
await nextTick();
feedback.value.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth", block: "center" });

